# The new Test Flight is worthless for adhoc distribution. Any work arounds?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution

I finally got an invite to an internal tester to work using iTunesConnect and the Test Flight app. I find that for adhoc distribution this is simply not going to work...

1. 30 day expiration is way too short.
2. In the old Test Flight, a tester had multiple devices. With the new test flight each invitation is good for only one device. If you try to use the invite on a different device it says it is already in use.

I don't see any work around for the expiration period, any ideas on a workaround for the second issue, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to add devices to the the user account.

Perhaps, this is not the vehicle I should use for my adhoc distributions? Other suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new TestFlight works better than the old one for multiple devices. The invite only works once, but it's tied to the Apple ID you use it with, log into the TestFlight app with that same Apple ID on another device and you can just install the app. Don't try to reuse the invite.

I personally find the Internal testers useless though, since you have to grant those users access to your iTunes Connect account. There's a work around where you can use your own email, something like "me+user1@whatever.com" and have the invite come to you, then you just forward the invite link to the user you want to use the build and not have access to iTC, but that's a pain.

The best plan is, send the app for TestFlight review, get it approved, then add all of your testers as External testers. You can submit new builds without going through review each time by keeping the version number (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) the same, increment the build number (`CFBundleVersion`), and checking the option that says "no significant changes for this build".

If you don't need to support iOS 7, the new TestFlight is way better than the old one. With the initial review being the only downside.

Comment: Good to know that you can install on different devices by logging into test flight with the same apple ID. I can't test this, however, because Test Flight automatically logged me in with a different apple ID (I have 2 apple IDs which sucks) and I do not see any way to log out of Test Flight so I can log back in with a different Apple ID. I tried deleting the app and reinstalling it, but it still automatically logged me in. I will take your word for it, and continue testing. Thanks.

Comment: It uses the Apple ID that you're logged into the store with, so log out of the store, and back in with the other Apple ID and you'll see the other apps in TestFlight. I also use multiple Apple ID's (so I can access both the US and Canadian stores).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Ok devices are no longer an issue. Unless going through the review process removes or extends the 30 day expiration, I am still not in a good place with this new process. I am supporting 1 client with 6 devices so I think Enterprise is overkill for me. It would be worth my time to just go to the client site and install on their devices from xCode. I think the ultimate answer might be do what it takes to put the app in the app store and let the client get updates from there.

Comment: The 30 days is per build, so just upload another build before then. Keep the version number the same, check the box as stated above, and the build is instantly approved ready for you to release to testers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick guide that explains what you can do with the New TF:
[New TestFlight • Quick need-to-know guide](https://medium.com/@MatCegiela/new-testflight-quick-need-to-know-guide-465a17347942)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of.

1. Get OS X Server and add the phones individually to your Provisioning profile. You will be limited to 100 phones, but any of those phones can login to the server and download the latest build on to their device.
2. Get an Enterprise account. You can't release to the App Store with an Enterprise account however.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your devices to testfairy from test flight

https://app.testfairy.com/testers/testflight-export/

This I haven't tried yet.